# Seeking Embedded Database alternative to SQLite. Must have foreign key contraint and transaction support?

Tags: database, sqlite, transactions, foreign-keys, embedded-database

Do you know of any SQLite alternatives (Portable/flatfile based/serverless) that have foreign key constraint and/or offer transaction support?

Comment: Knowing what language you're working with would help - there's numerous embedded Java databases like HSQL, Derby, etc.

Comment: embedded into what? language, runtime?

Comment: Why don't you want to use SQLite?

Comment: @Sam, Because of the lack of foreign key constraint (ignore the transaction support - that was my mistake, sqlite does have it). I will need cascade for udpate/delete functions - and was wondering if I can get by without writing my own routines.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop - I didn't use that word embedded - that was some AI modification of what I wrote. But I think it means embedded within the application regardless of the platform (iphone/PC/web app etc).

Comment: @prateek-kumar, Even before SQLite officially supported foreign key support, many achieved it through triggers. If you need cascading updates/deletes, you can do it through triggers.

Comment: it wasn't "AI" it was another user, OMG Ponies specifically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 3.6.19, SQLite [supports foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

And as far as I know it already supports transactions? What did you have in mind?

Comment: And before 3.6.19, you could write triggers to enforce foreign key constraints.  There was a `genfkey` program for this.